# Umbraco 7 URL rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to add url rewrites

My current URL http://some_domain.co.uk/category/page_name/

I am trying to keep existing site urls functioning with below URL

http://some_domain.co.uk/category/page_name.htm

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

i would highly recommend keeping the current URL structure, it's cleaner, and maintainability will be easier.

If your worried about the SEO or the dead links after the new site goes live then how about doing 301 redirect instead?

Umbraco has a plugin that helps you do 301 redirect and keep track of all the 404 pages, and you can view the report and 301 redirect those 404 pages.

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker

In the example above,
http://some_domain.co.uk/category/page_name.htm

will get redirected to

http://some_domain.co.uk/category/page_name/